# How can I make sure that numbers in 17 variables are different?

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

I have 17 variables (S1, S2... S17) and I need to check that they are all different. Is there any way to do this other than

```
if S1 != S2 and S1!=S3...
```

because I don't really want to write 136 statements. Some method of a list, maybe?

Comment: What are the types of those variables?

Comment: @thefourtheye, just integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all those data are hashable, you can simply construct a set and check its length, like this

```
if len({s1, s2, s3..., s17}) == 17:
   # All are not equal
```

For example, if all them are just integers, like [you mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232786/make-sure-that-17-values-are-not-equal-python/29232829#comment46671611_29232786),

```
>>> s1, s2, s3 = 1, 1, 1
>>> len({s1, s2, s3})
1
>>> s1, s2, s3 = 1, 2, 3
>>> len({s1, s2, s3})
3
```

If all the numbers are the same, then set will have only 1 element as all the duplicates are removed. So to check if all the elements are different, just compare the length of the set against the total number of variables.

---

Instead, you can write the conditions straight forward, like this

```
if not (s1 == s2 == s3 == .... s17):
   # All are not equal
```

**Internally**, Python will execute it like this

```
if not ((s1 == s2) and (s2 == s3) and (s3 == s4) ... and (s16 == s17)):
   # All are not equal
```

Comment: if `s1==s2==...s17` time consuming?

Comment: @itzmeontv Thats another straight forward method. I just included and explained how it works. Thanks :-)

Comment: @itzmeontv I don't understand: `s1==s2==...s17` AFAICT this will test if _all_ values are the same. And `s1!=s2!=...s17` will assume that duplicates are _consecutive_ values. None of them apply to the OP use case -- or do I missed something ? (`1 != 2 != 1` => `True` but `2 != 1 != 1` => `False`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `any()`

```
>>> l = [1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8]

>>> any(l.count(x) > 1 for x in l)

True

>>> l = [1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8]

>>> any(l.count(x) > 1 for x in l)

False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put all of the variables in a list. When you convert it to a set and the length of this set is still 17, all of the variables are unique. If there are duplicate values, the newly created set will be less than 17. So you can convert a list with the variables stored in it to a set and check whether the length of the list and set are the same.